# Postgresql query - overlapping OR conditions

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with multiple boolean columns, and parameters passed into the query which decide what data is loaded.
Let's say each column has its own parameter - true or false.
If a column has a TRUE parameter, both TRUE and FALSE rows need to be loaded.
If a column has a FALSE parameter, only FALSE rows need to be loaded.

The tricky part for me is that even if there is a FALSE parameter for col1, if there is a TRUE parameter for col2 then that row has to be loaded anyway. Let me try and put an example:

```
    col1   col2
1   TRUE   FALSE
2   TRUE   TRUE
3   FALSE  FALSE
```

if col1_param is TRUE and col2_param is TRUE, rows 1 and 2 need to be loaded.
if col1_param is FALSE and col2_param is TRUE, rows rows 1 and 2 need to be loaded.
if col1_param is FALSE and col2_param is FALSE, only row 3 needs to be loaded.

This has been one of my attemps so far:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE
   CASE
      WHEN col1_param IS TRUE THEN TRUE
      ELSE col1 IS FALSE
   END
UNION
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE
   CASE
      WHEN col2_param IS TRUE THEN TRUE
      ELSE col2 IS FALSE
   END
```

But it wasn't giving the results needed...

Also please take into account there are up to 7 columns like this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you state that "If a column has a TRUE parameter, both TRUE and FALSE rows need to be loaded.", then why, when col1_param and col2_param are both TRUE, row 3 does not get loaded? Can you provide a complete truth table for, say, the two-column case (should be 16 lines in total)?

Comment: So basically if the param is TRUE, load both TRUE and FALSE, if the param is FALSE, only FALSE, does that make sense?

Comment: Well your description and the example for parameters true, true are inconsistent. You must explain why the row 3 is not loaded if you accept both true and false.

Answer (score 0):

With this sample data

```
create table tab (id serial, col1 boolean, col2 boolean);

insert into tab (col1,col2) values (true, false);
insert into tab (col1,col2) values (true, true);
insert into tab (col1,col2) values (false, false);
insert into tab (col1,col2) values (false, true);

select * from tab;

id|col1 |col2 |
--+-----+-----+
 1|true |false|
 2|true |true |
 3|false|false|
 4|false|true |
```

Use this query based on *your description* (not on *your inconsistent exaples*)

```
select * from tab where 
case when :col1_param then col1 is not null
else col1 is false 
end 
AND
case when :col2_param then col2 is not null
else col2 is false 
end
```

The query returns following data for the paramater combinations:

```
-- par1 TRUE, par2 TRUE
id|col1 |col2 |
--+-----+-----+
 1|true |false|
 2|true |true |
 3|false|false|
 4|false|true |
 
-- par1 TRUE, par2 FALSE 
id|col1 |col2 |
--+-----+-----+
 1|true |false|
 3|false|false|
 
 -- par1 FALSE, par2 TRUE
id|col1 |col2 |
--+-----+-----+
 3|false|false|
 4|false|true |
 
-- par1 FALSE, par2 FALSE
id|col1 |col2 |
--+-----+-----+
 3|false|false|
```

Note that the example used not nullable data, but  I'm using `is not null` to exclude a column with a `null` value for a TRUE parameter.